# Let $g$ be a differentiable, nonnegative and decreasing function on $(0,\infty)$. Then $\int_k^{\infty} \, g(x) \, dx \approx 0$

Tags: calculus, improper-integrals

I am doing some work in probability and mathematical statistics, and I'm frequently engaged with nonnegative and decreasing functions on $(0,\infty)$. Some of the calculations would be smoother if the following conjecture is true, which I can see being true intuitively. So I formulated a conjecture, but I'm not sure how to prove it. Another obstacle is that I would like to have a more rigorous meaning as to what $\approx 0$ means.

Could someone help me or give me a hint as to how I can prove the following or provide a counterexample? I haven't gotten far.

$$\textbf{Conjecture}$$
Let $g$ be a differentiable, nonnegative and monotonically decreasing function on $(0,\infty)$. 
Then there exists $k \in \operatorname{dom}(g)$ such that
$$\int_k^{\infty} \, g(x) \, dx \approx 0$$

Comment: No. Consider $g(x)=e^{-x}+42$.

Answer (score 1):

$g(x)=1/x$, for $\displaystyle\int_{k}^{\infty}\dfrac{1}{x}dx=\infty$, so that is not true.

Comment: Ah, very nice counterexample.

In that case, it would seem another assumption that has to be made is that the antiderivative $G$ of $g$ must also be nonnegative and decreasing?

Comment: Actually it is about some sort of rate of decreasing at infinity should be made.

Comment: If $g$ is integrable, then it goes through.

Comment: Isn’t the $\frac{1}{x}$ in your example integrable? If so, what do you mean by integrable?

Comment: It is not integrable, integrability means that the value is $<\infty$.

Comment: Would you mind providing a proof? I've tried my hand at it, but I keep getting stuck. My initial strategy was to somehow force
$\int_k^{\infty} \, g(x) \, dx = 0$ somehow, but I keep going in circles.

Comment: By Monotone Convergence Theorem $\displaystyle\int_{0}^{k}g(x)dx\rightarrow\displaystyle\int_{0}^{\infty}g(x)dx$, but the first term is just $\displaystyle\int_{k}^{\infty}g(x)dx$.